# C# Windows Service "Pauses" System when starting during boot

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, service, network-programming

I've written a windows service that consumes a WCF Web Service that monitors various system activity. 
Its Startup type is set to Automatic and it starts as expected when the system boots up. While doing some testing in a Windows 7 VirtualBox VM I noticed that the initial call to the WCF service was timing out.

After doing some research i found that in any of my c# services making any kind of call out to the internet without letting the system "Settle Down" for a bit after boot results in the system essentially hanging for about a minute and a half. I tried this on other bare metal boxes and the times are a bit shorter but it still happens.
(Probably why I haven't noticed before now.)
So the symptoms seem to be this. If I set the service startup to Automatic (Delayed Start) a test service that only hits an IP website executes immediately with no delay.  If i cause the service to Start automatically and Sleep about 20 seconds first, it also executes immediately with no delay.  If i try to execute the command immediately upon startup the service just sits there for 1:15 to 1:45.

The preliminary conclusion is that there is a process that is starting when i'm trying to access the network, but i'm at a loss as to determine what is causing this.
I could set the service to delayed start and be done with it, but that offends my sense of doing things correctly.

If it's a service that is starting i want to make my service depend on it...etc.
Any ideas?

I tried to be thorough, but it's my first question. I'll happily provide any additional details.  Thanks.

**Here is the Test services OnStart Event:**

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Logging.WriteLog("Starting");

        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Tcpip");
        Logging.WriteLog("TCPIP Status: " +sc.Status.ToString());

        sc = new ServiceController("DHCP");
        Logging.WriteLog("DHCP Status: " + sc.Status.ToString());

        sc = new ServiceController("Dnscache");
        Logging.WriteLog("DNS Status: " + sc.Status.ToString());

        Logging.WriteLog("Internal IP: " + getInternalIp());

        Logging.WriteLog("External IP: " + getExternalIp());
        Logging.WriteLog("Stopping");
    }
```

**Here is the code for the getExternalIP method:**

```
       private string getExternalIp()
    {
        try
        {
            string externalIP = "";
            try
            {
                //code hangs here
                externalIP = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://ipv4.icanhazip.com");
                externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
                             .Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.WriteLog(ex);
            }
            return externalIP;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.WriteLog(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Here is the output for Immediate Start:**

3/16/2017 7:57:08 AM: Starting

3/16/2017 7:57:09 AM: TCPIP Status: Running

3/16/2017 7:57:09 AM: DHCP Status: Running

3/16/2017 7:57:09 AM: DNS Status: Running

3/16/2017 7:57:11 AM: Internal IP: 192.168.2.103

**3/16/2017 7:58:30 AM:** External IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  <-- 1 min 19 sec delay

3/16/2017 7:58:30 AM: Stopping

**And here is Delayed Start Output:**

3/16/2017 8:03:39 AM: Starting

3/16/2017 8:03:39 AM: TCPIP Status: Running

3/16/2017 8:03:39 AM: DHCP Status: Running

3/16/2017 8:03:39 AM: DNS Status: Running

3/16/2017 8:03:40 AM: INternal IP: 192.168.2.103

**3/16/2017 8:03:40 AM:** External IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx <-- No Delay

3/16/2017 8:03:40 AM: Stopping

Comment: I use Automatic (Delayed Start) for in-house services often to allow low-level services to start up first.  Alternatively, you could do the research to determine precisely which services your service needs, and configure them as dependencies for your service.  http://serverfault.com/questions/24821/how-to-add-dependency-on-a-windows-service-after-the-service-is-installed

Answer (score 0):

Use Async in your app so the the main thread will not stop.  However this will break your consistency of showing "Stopping" first then the IP since the call to the external website might take some time to resolve.  I suggest to call the ExternalIP

```
  WebClient client = new WebClient();
  client.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadDataCompleted;
  client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://ipv4.icanhazip.com"));


static void DownloadDataCompleted(object sender,
    DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] raw = e.Result;
    string data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(raw);
    data = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
                             .Matches(data)[0].ToString();
    Logging.WriteLog("External IP: " + data);                            
}
```